# SunOS sccs - How do I edit files checked out by people who no longer work here

Tags: version-control, sunos

I have a problem. the documentation assumes that people who checked out the files a long time ago can be contacted, log in and check out their changes.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-1075/msgs-1307/index.html

I am logged in to a SunOS box where I need to discard edits made by people who no longer work here. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick answer.

sccs uses files.

In the SCCS directory (subfolder) the are files with almost the same name as the file being checked out.

Iirc:

Most of these are "s.", but there are a few others with relation to what state the files are in.

The s. files are big, the other files are small.

You should see a file in the SCCS folder that starts "p.", I think, and it should contain the username or the person checking the file out.  Delete the file and the record of the checked out file will be removed.

You'll also want to delete the filename from the parent directory, so that it can be checked out of the library easily.

There are other ways around it using sccs, but this is the easiest way to fix your issue.

Comment: I wanted to preserve the edits, so I ended up editing login in the "p." file, ownership of the "p." file and checked out file and then using normal sccs commands to commit the changes for someone else to review.